# Prometheus inhibiting but no matching instance label

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

So I have this Situation:
Blackbox-icmp, where the instance label is `example.com`
Blackbox-http, where the instance label is `https://example.com`
Node-exporter, where the instance label is `example.com:9100`

Now all of these reference the same server, and I have created an alert, that fires when both the blackbox-icmp fail and the node-exporter is down, an `InstanceDown` alert. Now the blackbox-http will also fire, since the http status code is now wrong, but I don't want the blackbox-http alert to also fire, when the `InstanceDown` alert is already firing.

The problem I have with this is, that the instance labels are all different even though it's the same server. How can I inhibit this? The only workaround I could come up with is by adding another, kind of redundant, label like "domain" to every job, so I can use that in the `equals` list for inhibiting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Prometheus "relabel_config" feature, for example, you can change all different instance labels to just "example".

**Blackbox-icmp**

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: '([a-z]+)\.com'
    replacement: ${1}
    target_label: instance
```

**Blackbox-http**

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: 'https//([a-z]+)\.com'
    replacement: ${1}
    target_label: instance
```

**Node-Exporter**

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: '([a-z]+)\..*'
    replacement: ${1}
    target_label: instance
```

**Important**

Keep also the regular Blackbox relabel_configs rules like in the example [here](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter)

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    target_label: __param_target
  - source_labels: [__param_target]
    target_label: instance
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: 127.0.0.1:9115  # The blackbox exporter's real hostname:port.
```

See more info in the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config).

Comment: But this would also change the address where the probe is actually going or where the node exporter is expected.

Comment: You need to keep the regular Blackbox relabel_configs rules like described in the example at the Blackbox README. I just updated the answer.